# DNN site won't display after clearing cache

Tags: dotnetnuke, webmatrix

I'm developing my first DNN based site and after having some problem with a 'Show on All Pages' module I cleared the cache.

Now the site won't display at all (Web matrix-IISExpress).

I can access the database tables and all the files but they won't load in a browser.

How do I get the site working again?

Answer (score 0):

I think I worked it out.

I found the Host Settings table and turned the Performance setting to the max "6".

I'd also been playing around with the Local port number but reverted to the standard port when I discovered that DNN sites are 'tied' to host settings.

After restarting the site came back.